# Jquery UI + Mobile Autocomplete Issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-autocomplete

When using auto complete, it shows up the suggestion inputs, if you click on one where it has a button underneath it, it clicks the button rather than the suggestion.

I've prepared a JS fiddle with the issues to see if anyone can help...

http://jsfiddle.net/XuZBt/8/

Is there anyway i can set the auto complete to be on top so this doesn't happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason your z-indexes are wrong. This works in FF on jsFiddle:

```
<input type="text" id="personHomeNum" data-autofill="N/A" data-stat="KNOWN" style="z-index: 1" />
<input type="button" value="Validate" id="validation_btn" style="z-index: 1"/>
```

For some reason this seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/XuZBt/20/

Comment: This doesnt allow me to click the button normally though?

Comment: See my update, if both are set to z-index=1, it works. check on http://jsfiddle.net/XuZBt/20/

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

With a couple slight CSS tweaks we can set the autocomplete widget above the button. The button's `z-index` is designated by it's ascendant `data-role="page"` `z-index` because the `data-role="page"` and `.ui-autocomplete` elements are siblings. If you attempt to change the `z-index` of the button inside the `data-role="page"` element it won't affect it in most browsers with respect to the autocomplete widget (it'll work in some browsers, but not others).

Here is all of the CSS required:

```
/*this rule makes the links in the autocomplete list block elements so they expand to fill their parents*/
​.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
    display : block;
}

/*this rule just sets the autocomplete menu above the data-role="page" element*/
.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu {
    z-index : 10;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XuZBt/21/